# Laravel Filter Items by relationships field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have the following query:

```
$job = Job::with('customer', 'location', 'projects.transactions', 'projects.workorders.tasks','projects.workorders', 'projects.prods.category')
    ->find($id);
```

How would I go about only getting results for products that have a category setting of show_in_products set to true? The field is defined in that `projects.prods.category` and I only want to see the products that should be shown. I have not had any success with a global scope or a `whereHas`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only getting results for products that have a catagory setting of
> show_in_products set to true

Assuming your products are in `prods` relationship, then you can filter your products in `with('projects.prods')`

```
$job = Job::with([
    'customer',
    'location',
    'projects.transactions',   
    'projects.workorders.tasks',
    'projects.workorders',
    'projects.prods' => function($prods) {
        $prods->whereHas('category', function($category) {
            $category->where('show_in_products', true);
        })
        ->with('category');
    }
])
->find($id);
```

So what's going on is you filter the result of `projects.prods`
by the constraint in `category` table `$prods->whereHas(...)`
then load `category` along with `prods` `->with('category')`.

By the way, `with('projects.workorders')` is redundant since you already have `with('projects.workorders.tasks')`

Comment: Thank you Anurat this worked. Also, thanks for the small code modification.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
$job = Job::with('customer', 'location', 'projects.transactions', 'projects.workorders.tasks','projects.workorders', 'projects.prods', 'projects.prods.category')
whereHas('projects.prods.category', function($q) {
   $q->where('show_in_products', true);
})->find($id);
```

Hope it helpes

Comment: This is exactly what I tried and it gives me the product but no category now it is just null. This category relationship is via a hasOneThrough relationship if that helps.

Comment: Also, I do get category relationship for ones that are marked true just null for ones that are marked false.

Comment: add 'projects.prods' to see what happens, this function should work.